# intersecting two multi key indexes for two fields (holding array values) in a document in mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, indexing

When using the `find` method, only the last or first index are being applied. How can I overcome the below scenario?

Sample document:

```
{ 
   "_id":"5a67xxxxxx",
   "name":"abc",
   "address":"Newyork",
   "type":[ "perm", "vend", "contract" ],
   "region":[ "USA", "MEA", "UK" ]
}
```

Indexes created for type and region: `_type_1` and `_region_1`:

```
{ 
   "name":"region_1",
   "key":{ 
      "region":1
   },
   "type":"REGULAR",
   "ns":“xxx.sample   ", },
{ 
   "name":"_type_1",
   "key":{ 
      "type":1
   },
   "type":"REGULAR",
   "ns":“xxx.sample   ", }
```

Find query:

```js
db.sample.find({  _type_1:{$in:["perm","vend"]},  _region_1: {$in:["USA","MEA"]}})
```

On executing the query only `_region_1` is applied. How can I apply both indexes while executing the query?

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-intersection/) help? You may also run a query on either `type` or `region` indices, and then use filter to filter out the other. P.S. You may need to create a [compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/) of `type` and `region`.

Comment: @oneturkmen : Please do not try to create a compound index on two array fields, it doesn't work like that, Please check this ::(https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/#create-multikey-index) && work4passion : Usually mongoDB by itself should use your two individual indexes as a compound index(index-intersection) for your given query, it's not happening for a reason, as I've mentioned above as these two fields are arrays it might not be utilizing it's built-in feature, but I'm not sure how to effectively use indexes on two arrays like above..

Comment: Please post the index definition(s). Run the [explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/index.html) method on the query; the output will show a query plan with details of how indexe(s) are used; post this also. Also, post a clear sample document; what you had posted is not a valid document.

Comment: @prasad_:  ran explain for query, after which I came up with this above case. only _region_1 index gets applied.Hope the below helps better.

Comment: @prasad_ : explain query for above, Index Keys Examined:2; Query used the following index:region

Comment: @srinivasy: Yeah that's right .That's why I created separate indexes since it's two arrays.

Comment: @oneturkmen: actually both fields are used in filters. filter:{type: { $in: [ "perm", "vend" ] }, region:{$in: ["USA","UK"] } }

Comment: @prasad_: index definition{
  "name": "_region_1",
  "key": {
    "region": 1
  },
  "type": "REGULAR",
  "ns": “xxx.sample",
},
{
  "name": "_id_",
  "key": {
    "_id": 1
  },
  "type": "REGULAR",
  "ns": “xxx.sample",
},
{
  "name": "_type_1",
  "key": {
    "type": 1
  },
  "type": "REGULAR",
  "ns": “xxx.sample",
} .

Comment: @prasad_: valid document 
{
  "_id": "5a67xxxxxx",
  "name": "abc",
  "address": "Newyork",
  "type": [
    "perm",
    "vend",
    "contract"
  ],
  "region": [
    "USA",
    "MEA",
    "UK"
  ]
}

Answer (score 1):

Multi-key index is an index on a field with an array as value. As such MongoDB doesn't allow create one index with two array fields (a compound index with two array fields). But, you can create separate indexes, as in this case; two single field indexes, one on each of the array fields.

The idea that why MongoDB doesn't allow a compound index with two array fields is that when such an index is created the number of keys in the index and the size of the index will be huge, and is a problem using such index without performance problems.

How about index intersection? Two single multikey indexes used to filter documents within the same query.

I created a small collection of documents with similar structure as in the question post, and indexes. And, ran some similar queries with `explain()`. I changed the filter data on multiple queries. It is interesting, to note that sometimes the query plan showed that the optimizer is using the index on field A only and sometimes the field B only. But, never both at the same time. But, query plans also showed sometimes that the index intersection is considered, not selected but rejected by the optimizer; that is the rejected plan showed usage of index intersection of the two multikey indexes.

How do we know that a query used an index intersection? The explain output had shown the AND_SORTED stage.

The [index intersection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-intersection/index.html) documentation says that:

> To determine if MongoDB used index intersection, run explain(); the
>   results of explain() will include either an AND_SORTED stage or an
>   AND_HASH stage.

I had posted the "rejectedPlans" details at the bottom of this post.

Generally, you can force the query optimizer to select a particular index in favor of other index; by using the `hint()`. But in this case this does not work.

```
       "rejectedPlans" : [
               {
                       "stage" : "FETCH",
                       "filter" : {
                               "a" : {
                                       "$eq" : 2
                               }
                       },
                       "inputStage" : {
                               "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                               "keyPattern" : {
                                       "b" : 1
                               },
                               "indexName" : "b_1",
                               "isMultiKey" : true,
                               "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                       "b" : [
                                               "b"
                                       ]
                               },
                               "isUnique" : false,
                               "isSparse" : false,
                               "isPartial" : false,
                               "indexVersion" : 2,
                               "direction" : "forward",
                               "indexBounds" : {
                                       "b" : [
                                               "[2.0, 2.0]"
                                       ]
                               }
                       }
               },
               {
                       "stage" : "FETCH",
                       "filter" : {
                               "$and" : [
                                       {
                                               "a" : {
                                                       "$eq" : 2
                                               }
                                       },
                                       {
                                               "b" : {
                                                       "$eq" : 2
                                               }
                                       }
                               ]
                       },
                       "inputStage" : {
                               "stage" : "AND_SORTED",
                               "inputStages" : [
                                       {
                                               "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                               "keyPattern" : {
                                                       "a" : 1
                                               },
                                               "indexName" : "a_1",
                                               "isMultiKey" : true,
                                               "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                       "a" : [
                                                               "a"
                                                       ]
                                               },
                                               "isUnique" : false,
                                               "isSparse" : false,
                                               "isPartial" : false,
                                               "indexVersion" : 2,
                                               "direction" : "forward",
                                               "indexBounds" : {
                                                       "a" : [
                                                               "[2.0, 2.0]"
                                                       ]
                                               }
                                       },
                                       {
                                               "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                               "keyPattern" : {
                                                       "b" : 1
                                               },
                                               "indexName" : "b_1",
                                               "isMultiKey" : true,
                                               "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                       "b" : [
                                                               "b"
                                                       ]
                                               },
                                               "isUnique" : false,
                                               "isSparse" : false,
                                               "isPartial" : false,
                                               "indexVersion" : 2,
                                               "direction" : "forward",
                                               "indexBounds" : {
                                                       "b" : [
                                                               "[2.0, 2.0]"
                                                       ]
                                               }
                                       }
                               ]
                       }
               }
       ]
```

---

**[EDIT ADD]**:

The documents, indexes and queries:

```
{ _id: 1, a: [ 1, 2 ], b: [ 2, 8 ], c: "Both arrays" },
{ _id: 2, a: [ 1, 5, 9 ], b: [ 4, 8, 2 ], c: "AB arrays" }

db.multi.createIndex({ a: 1})
db.multi.createIndex({ b: 1})

db.multi.find( { a: { $in: [ 5, 9 ] }, b: { $in: [ 4 ] } } )
db.multi.find( { a: { $in: [ 2] }, b: { $in: [ 2 ] } } )
```

Comment: Thanks!! but I'm bot able to see AND_HASH / AND_SORTED in input stage after query explain. Means index intersection is not applied.

Comment: Yes, that means the index intersection is not applied.

Comment: can you share the query and indexes you created ?

Comment: Sure, the queries might be same or different.

Comment: yeah fine. But hope you created indexes for two array value fields and you tried to filter those. Because when I do that, Im not able to see AND_HASH/AND_SORTED

Comment: Thanks!! still I queried the same way but I'm not able to view in mongo DB compass on executing query plan

Comment: rejectedPlans:Array
0:Object
stage:"FETCH"
filter:Object
region:Object
$eq:"USA"
inputStage:Object
stage:"IXSCAN"
keyPattern:Object
type:1
indexName:"_type_1"
isMultiKey:true
multiKeyPaths:Object
type:Array
0:"type"
isUnique:false
isSparse:false
isPartial:false
indexVersion:2
direction:"forward"
indexBounds:Object
type:Array
0:"["perm", "perm"]"
1:"["vend", "vend"]"

Comment: Do we need to append any keywords in query during query explain ? because rejectedPlans shows me only the other index which is rejected.

Comment: This is the query which showed me the above query plan with the _rejected plan_ details: `db.multi.find( { a: { $in: [ 2] }, b: { $in: [ 2 ] } } ).explain()`

Comment: we are using 3.6 mongo version and MMAPV storage engine . May be because of which we are not able to view AND_SORTED / AND_HASH ? can you please confirm

Comment: I am using MongoDB 4.0.x version (this has WIredTiger as default). I don't know if the storage engine matters.

Comment: Because if you see AND_HASH / AND_SORTED. These are mentioned right from 3.0 version manual not below that

Comment: "stage" : "AND_SORTED" was not showing earlier when I used $in clause, instead I used $eq. This is still 3.6 version only. Kindly suggest here.